# how are hashes used to look up entries in a database?

Tags: hash

I'm reading Medium Staff's article on [Bloom filters](https://medium.com/the-story/what-are-bloom-filters-1ec2a50c68ff), and I found this snippet:

> When you ask the database for a specific post, how does it know where to find it? A hash function. The database takes the ID, hashes it to a unique value, and uses that to jump straight to the record location, just like you’d use the index of a book to jump straight to a specific page number

How exactly does this work in practice? If each ID is hashed, shouldnt the lookup time using the hash be the same as using the actual ID?

Comment: Hashes are often used for comparison because they are smaller than the object that was hashed. For example, if the article ID was a string of the article's title it might be dozens of bytes long, white the hash might be only a few bytes, making comparisons quicker.

Comment: The article mentions that the hashes were used to determine which machine of several the requested article was stored on. When articles are on different servers, you need a quick way to figure out which server it is on. Without using a hash, you might try something like assigning each article to a server based the first letter of the article, but this might not work well—many articles will end up starting with "T" ("The") or "W" ("What", "Why", etc.) in English, but few with "Q". A good hash should spread articles around evenly, so no one machine ends up with too much or too little load.

Comment: The root of what I'm trying to figure out is how can a hash be used to identify a server that an article is hosted on? Wouldnt it require in depth knowledge about a particular hashing algorithm to be able to tie its output reliably to another hash on a particular server? And in the same line of thinking, what if the hashing algorithm is changed?

Comment: Pick any good hashing algorithm; it doesn't matter which one. Now say you are using 3 bits of the hash to generate a number from 0 to 7. Thus any input can be assigned one of these numbers, and can be assigned to any of eight servers. It doesn't matter which server an input hashes to; as long as the hash algorithm never changes it can always be found quickly. If the algorithm changed, all the data would have to be moved around to put it on the new correct servers. ([Oracle does not let you change the hash algorithm](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm#i462869).)